# Permutations and Combinations of ways of dividing into identical and non- identical groups

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can $8$ people be divided into
>
> 1. $4$ groups of $2$ people
> 2. First pair, second pair. Third pair and the fourth pair

How do you go about doing this question?

Comment: Are you familiar with binomial coefficients? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

4 groups of 2 people:

```
  _ _      _ _      _ _      _ _
( 8.7/2! * 6.5/2! * 4.3/2! * 2.1/2! )/4!
```

First pair, second pair. Third pair and the fourth pair:

```
1º pair -> 8*7/2! = 28
2º pair -> 6*5/2! = 15
 ...    ->   ...
```

Comment: Use consistent notation, please.